# Make clean output in pyodbc using python and ms-access

Tags: qt, python-2.7, ms-access-2007, output, pyodbc

I make plugin that take record from ms-access database and put it in QT as recomendation, but when i run it it have the strage output, like this :

**(u'Ini Bessel dengan Bessel', )**

and the output i want is like this :

**Ini Bessel dengan Bessel**  (a clean output without bracket and 'u' thing)

This is code is use to make that plugin :

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from ui_testdbase import Ui_TestDbase
import pyodbc

class TestDbaseDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self)
        # Set up the user interface from Designer.
        self.ui = Ui_TestDbase()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        Rec_1 = self.ui.btnOke
        QtCore.QObject.connect(Rec_1, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'),self.Compskala)

    def query_odbc(self, sqlquery):

        db = 'd:/_tmp/Assessment.mdb'

        constr = 'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=' + db
        conn = pyodbc.connect(constr, autocommit=True)
        cur = conn.cursor()

        cur.execute(sqlquery)
        t = list(cur)
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
        return str(t).strip('[]')        


    def Compskala(self):

        skal1 = self.ui.lineSkal1.text()
        skal2 = self.ui.lineSkal2.text()
        bandskal = ''
        if skal1 in ['WGS84'] and skal2 in ['WGS84'] :      
            bandskal = self.query_odbc('''SELECT rekomendasi FROM datum where datum1 = 'wgs84' AND datum2 = 'wgs84';''')
        elif skal1 in ['DGN95'] and skal2 in ['WGS84'] :
            bandskal = self.query_odbc('''SELECT rekomendasi FROM datum where datum1 = 'wgs84' AND datum2 = 'dgn95';''')
        elif skal1 in ['bessel'] and skal2 in ['bessel'] :
            bandskal = self.query_odbc('''SELECT rekomendasi FROM datum where datum1 = 'bessel' AND datum2 = 'bessel';''')
        else:
            bandskal = 'Karena perbedaan skala dasar Peta tidak dapat dipadukan'

        self.ui.textBrow1.setPlainText(bandskal)
```

Can Someone help me to solve this?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```python
t = list(cur)
```

When converted to a string, `str(t)` becomes

```
[(u'Ini Bessel dengan Bessel', )]
```

Rather than trying to use "brute force" to strip out the extraneous characters with ...

```python
return str(t).strip('[]')
```

... perhaps you could just extract the string from the list. If all you want is the first column of the first row in the list (cursor) then try just using

```python
return t[0][0]
```